# Do very small MySQL tables ignore indexes?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

After turning on `log_queries_not_using_indexes`, I noticed that one query was rapidly filling up the slow query log:

`SELECT abc.* FROM abc
WHERE abc.id
NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT abc_id FROM zyx
    WHERE id = 12345
);`

`abc` is very small, just 3 rows of data. `zyx` is relatively large with over 100,000 rows of data.

`abc.id` has an index, but when I `EXPLAIN` the query, the index isn't listed under either `key` nor `possible_keys`. This explains why the query is showing in the slow log, but my question is, why isn't it using the index?

In short, I have two questions:

1. Do very small tables ignore indexes? I could see why, it doesn't save much time to use an index on 3 rows of data.
2. If so, how can I prevent this query from flooding my slow query log?

Thank you for your time! :)

Additional information, if needed:

I have run `ANALYZE TABLE abc` as I've read sometimes fixes the issue. I have also restarted MariaDB since adding the index.

More of the `EXPLAIN`: select_type=PRIMARY, table=abc, type=ALL, possible_keys=NULL, key=NULL, key_len=NULL, ref=NULL, rows=3, Extra=Using where

Comment: It's highly unlike the lack of an index on a small table is causing the query to be slow. Is there an index on `zyx.id`?

Comment: @Uueerdo The OP isn't implying that the query is slow; just that it's appearing in the slow query log. (Which logs all queries meeting certain criteria, not just ones that actually take a lot of time.)

Comment: @duskwuff ah, true; I overlooked that he never actually said the query itself was slow.

Comment: @Uueerdo yes, there is an index on zyx.id (and zyx.abc_id), and EXPLAIN is indicating that it's using an index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do very small tables ignore indexes?

Yes. When the entire table can be read in a single disk access, there's no point in performing a separate disk access to read the index.

> If so, how can I prevent this query from flooding my slow query log?

Turn off `log_queries_not_using_indexes`. This is one of the reasons why it isn't on by default.

Answer (score 1):

`NOT IN ( SELECT ... )` is very poorly optimized, especially in older versions.

Change to this:

```
SELECT  abc.*
    FROM  abc
    LEFT JOIN  zyx  ON zyx.abc_id = abc.id
    WHERE  zyx.abc_id IS NULL;
AND  zyx.id = 12345 ;
```

For zyx, have either `INDEX(id, abc_id)` or `INDEX(abc_id, id)`

If `zyx.id` is the `PRIMARY KEY`, your query does not make much sense -- why test for a single row (12345)?